# Vector initialisation using ranges vs lambda inline initialisation

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I would like to initialise a vector by transforming the other one. I made a test with two ways of inline initialisation a transformed `std::vector`.

One using lambda inline initialisation (with `std::transform`):

```cpp
   std::vector<int> foo(100,42);
   const auto fooTimesTwo = [&]{
            std::vector<int> tmp(foo.size());
            std::transform(foo.begin(), foo.end(), tmp.begin(), convert);
            return tmp;
    }();
```

And the other one - using `std::ranges::views::transform`:

```cpp
   std::vector<int> foo(100,42);
   auto transform_range = (foo | std::ranges::views::transform(convert));
   std::vector<int> fooTimesTwo {
           transform_range.begin(),
           transform_range.end()
   };
```

I expected that both way of vector initialisation should have similar performance, but from some reason the benchmark of solution with traditional `std::transform` is much faster that the second one (9.7 times faster -> https://quick-bench.com/q/3PSDRO9UbMNunUpdWGNShF49WlQ ).

My questions are:

- Do I use `std::ranges::views::transform` incorrectly?
- Why does it work so much slower?

Side note - it can be done using `boost::make_transform_iterator`, but I couldn't check it on quick-bench as they don't support boost. So I'm not sure about efficiency of such solution.

Comment: Ranges can be inefficient. But it's easy. What's `convert` doing?

Comment: Multiplies an integer by two.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Why does it work so much slower?

The problem you're running into is one of the differences between the C++98/C++17 iterator model and the C++20 iterator model. One of the old requirements for `X` to be a forward iterator [was](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterators#forward.iterators-1.3):

> if `X` is a mutable iterator, `reference` is a reference to `T`; if `X` is a constant iterator, `reference` is a reference to `const T`,

That is, the iterator's `reference` type *had* to be a true reference. It could not be a proxy reference or a prvalue. *Any* iterator whose `reference` is a prvalue is automatically an input iterator only.

There is no such requirement in C++20.

So if you look at `foo | std::ranges::views::transform(convert)`, this is a range of prvalue `int`. In the C++20 iterator model, this is a random access range. But in the C++17, because we're dealing with prvalues, this is an *input range only*.

`vector`'s iterator-pair constructor is not based on the C++20 iterator model, it is based on the C++98/C++17 iterator model. It's using the old understanding of iterator category, not the new understanding. And the C++20 range adaptors work very hard to ensure that they do the "right thing" with respect to the old iterator model. Our adapted range does correctly advertise itself as random access when checked as C++20 and input when checked as C++17:

```cpp
void f(std::vector<int> v) {
    auto r = v | std::views::transform(convert);
    using R = decltype(r);
    static_assert(std::ranges::random_access_range<R>);
    static_assert(std::same_as<std::input_iterator_tag,
        std::iterator_traits<std::ranges::iterator_t<R>>::iterator_category>);
}
```

So what happens when you pass two input iterators into `vector`'s iterator pair constructor? Well, it can't allocate a huge chunk up front (we can't do `last - first` here because it's an input iterator, the notion that having a "sized sentinel" might be independent from the traversal category is also a new thing in the C++20 iterator model)... instead it basically does this:

```cpp
for (; first != last; ++first) {
    push_back(*first);
}
```

Can't do any better than that for an input iterator. But that's super inefficient, because we end up doing like eight allocations instead of one.

---

In range-v3, you can do this:

```cpp
auto result = foo | ranges::views::transform(convert)
                  | ranges::to<std::vector>();
```

The `to` algorithm understands the C++20 iterator model and does the right thing by reserving in advance here. However, `to` is very limited in the fact that it's an external library and we can't just modify standard library types to opt into it. We hope to have a `std::ranges::to` in C++23 that will come with improvements to the standard library containers to do this even better. At that point, this solution will be better than your original solution since `std::vector<int> foo(tmp.size())` is itself wasteful by having to zero-initialize a chunk of memory, only to immediately overwrite it.

---

In the meantime, I do wonder both about the general value of preserving this `reference`-must-be-reference requirement (that few people even know about and probably even fewer rely on: the biggest value is probably just knowing that `operator->()` can return `&operator*()`?).

`std::vector<bool>` already lies about this and advertises itself as being a random access C++17 range, for instance.

Standard library implementations though should be able to handle this case better. They should be able to safely check for the C++20 iterator concepts and do something intelligent as a result. In this case, we have C++20 random access iterators, so `vector` *should* be able to construct itself efficiently in this context. Submitted [100070](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100070).

Comment: If I understood correctly - just doing reserve solves the problem: `std::vector<int> fooTimesTwo; fooTimesTwo.reserve(foo.size()); fooTimesTwo.assign(transform_range.begin(), transform_range.end());`

Comment: @PiotrNycz. No, is still super inefficient, and why this "not works" is unclear. (https://quick-bench.com/q/jsxa0cw4CSrzdwkYkuVB5JLqsuU)

Comment: I found a version that is equal to non-range solution: https://quick-bench.com/q/7bPK8ucYrfWKrBIX-Bhp0bv4uhU  - vector foo2 is constructed in the same way - and instead of assing - simple copy. It seems that sequnce of push/emplace_back is a problem

Comment: It seems that deleted answer from @cigien is correct - maybe against "theory" - but it works

Comment: @PiotrNycz. Can you tell me what he said?

Comment: he advices to do `std::vector<int> fooTimesTwo(foo.size()); std::ranges::copy(foo | std::ranges::views::transform(convert),                  fooTimesTwo.begin());` which is probaly the same or better performance, but did not recognize the fact the transform shall produce random-access-iterators and thus - reserve should be done automatic. But as you checked - reserve did not really help

Comment: @PiotrNycz. But you are using the `std::copy` instead of `range::cpoy`. In theory, it should also not recognize the random-access iterator.

Comment: it container is already resized to its wanted size - then iterator category is irrelevant - iterators can be just input iterators